# Is the ring of power series with coefficients in a field free as a module over the polynomials subring?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Is the ring of power series with coefficients in a field free as a module over the polynomials subring?

Comment: Obviously not (since $k[[x]]$ is $(x-1)$-divisible).

Comment: Reading this title in the How Network questions list, I initially thought it was going to be a Tolkien question from [SFF.stackexchange](https://scifi.stackexchange.com)…

Answer (score 12):

No. Take some element $f$ of $K[x]$ which is not in the ideal $(x)$ and is not invertible. Then
$$K[[x]] \otimes_{K[x]} K[x]/(f) \cong K[[x]]/(f) = 0$$
where the latter follows from the fact that since $f \notin (x)$, it becomes invertible in $K[[x]]$.

In particular, $K[[x]]$ is not faithfully flat over $K[x]$, so it, being a nonzero module, cannot be free over it.